# Is it possible to have angular-cli project within backend git repo?

Tags: git, angular, github, angular-cli

I initially created a git repo for backend of my app and a repo for the frontend, but I have found it better to have the frontend (angular-cli project) within the backend repo like so:

```
MAIN-PROJECT
├── Backend Files (routes, models, package.json, .git, .gitignore, node_modules etc.)
├── public (ng build output)
├── angular-src ()
│   ├── Angular cli files (src, node_modules, package.json, .git, .gitignore)
```

What is the best way to turn this into a single project so I can push it to Github? I have tried making it a git submodule, but I wasn't sure it was what I wanted or how it worked, so I changed it back.

Comment: why not just copy the "frontend (angular-cli project)" into a folder and push it to the backend repo? if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam Well that's what I currently have but the angular project, even after deleting .git in the angular project folder, it still does not want to merge with the root project. They have a separate package.json, node_modules etc. but I don't see how that could be a problem... When viewing git status, it says something like "angular-src (untracked changes, something else)".

Comment: you cant have 2 package.json files in the same folder. Npm cant tell which to use. It has to be in a sub-directory. For untracked changes use 'git add *' then commit as you usually do.